# AWS SES error sending emails to partners with multiple emails in Odoo

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, smtp, amazon-ses, odoo-14

I'm working with Odoo14, using AWS SES as SMTP to send emails, but I have an error when trying to send the invoice mail to partners who have multiple emails (for example: partner1@mail.com,partner2@mail,partner3@mail.com) the email is not sent and I got the following error:

```
Unknown error: Mail Delivery Failed
Mail delivery failed via SMTP server 'None'.
SMTPDataError: 554
Transaction failed: Missing '<'
```

This error only occurs when I try to send the email with AWS SES SMTP, if I use other SMTP like my gmail account, the emails are being sent correctly without any problem.

I appreciate the help!

Comment: Did you configure the outgoing smtp server with no errors in Odoo?

Comment: @JuanSalcedo yes it's configured fine because all the other emails are being sent correctly, only if I try to send an email to a customer with multiple emails are not working.